# Titanium hybrid app - html page zoomed in in samsum s7

Tags: html, mobile, zooming

We have a hybrid app build in titanium. It works fine except in some new phones (such as Galaxy s7 active as far as I know). On those phones, the html page is zoomed in even though I have the following viewport meta tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />`

I have tried different options but nothing seems to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Again the problem is that when the webview opens the html page, the page is zoomed in.

Comment: Why develop a webpage with titanium? Titanium lets you build proper hybrid apps without any html

Comment: OK, I think I figured out this issue. The problem was with pixel ratio. The pixel ratio on the device that was causing this problem is 4. Hence the initial scale "1" was not appropriate due to the high density of the screen.

Comment: In that case, this issue is irrelevant to titanium as it is just a webview/website problem

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured out this issue. The problem was with the pixel ratio. The pixel ratio on the device that was causing this problem is 4. Hence the initial scale "1" was not appropriate due to the high density of the screen.  Thanks to the following article I was able to create a JavaScript function that adjusts the initial scale based on the pixel ratio of the screen.

Here is the article https://coderwall.com/p/ikrswg/bootstrap-3-grid-system-and-hi-density-small-screens-detected-as-xs
Many thanks to the guy who wrote it.

Here is the meta tags that you need to put in the header of your page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
 <head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Here is the JavaScript function that you can call in every page to adjust the scale

```js
function FixScreenScale(){
 if ((window.devicePixelRatio || 1) == 1) return;
 
 var scale = 1 / (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
 var content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=' + scale + ', minimum-scale=' + scale + ', maximum-scale=' + scale + ', user-scalable=0';
 document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute('content', content);
}
```